# Erro ao usar activities em um pacote filho

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, packages

Estou com um problema em meu projeto Android no Eclipse. Após ir implementando as funcionalidades, cheguei a um total de 10 activities e mais 8 outras classes. A partir daí percebi a necessidade de estruturar o código e criei pacotes filhos dentro do pacote do projeto ficando da seguinte maneira:

[image: Estrutura do Projeto]

Lembrando que pra que o Eclipse exiba os pacotes dessa forma eu mudei o modo de visualização dos pacotes para exibir por hierarquia.

Dentro do pacote activities eu coloquei todas as activities do projeto. Ao salvar tudo e rodar recebo o seguinte erro:

```
01-03 19:59:59.630: E/AndroidRuntime(361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 19:59:59.630: E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.meu_projeto/com.example.meu_projeto.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.meu_projeto.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.meu_projeto-1.apk]
01-03 19:59:59.630: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
```

Já tentei fazer essa mudança no *AndroidManifest.xml*:

Antes:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Depois mudei esta linha:

```
android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
```

Mas não adiantou, alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Coloque uma imagem da estrutura da pasta `/src/`

Comment: Ok vou colocar.

Comment: Pronto coloquei a imagem, espero que alguém possa responder pq eu não achei a solução disso ainda.

Comment: Renomeie todas as pastas com `com.example.meu_projeto.` na frente. Exemplo a pasta tasks ficaria: `com.example.meu_projeto.tasks`

Comment: Mas elas estão renomeadas dessa forma, o Eclipse mostra daquele jeito pq coloquei pra exibir de forma hierarquica.

Comment: Tem como adicionar o androidmanifest completo?

Comment: @Diego Felipe já resolvi graças a solução do Jackowski e com a ajuda do seu comentário obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O package da sua classe MainActivity está errado. Altere o atributo "name" da sua classe MainActivity no seu AndroidManifest.xml ficando da seguinte forma:

Antes:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Depois altere apenas esta linha:

```
android:name="com.example.meu_projeto.activities.MainActivity"
```

Você deverá aplicar essa mudança no AndroidManifest.xml em todas as activities que estiverem no pacote filho.

Comment: Você quer dizer isso:   package com.example.meu_projeto.activities;                                                                  já fiz.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante coloque no atributo `android:name` como o  Jackowski mostrou que irá funcionar.

Comment: @GustavoAlmeidaCavalcante só mostra esse erro? Não tem nenhum outro aviso?

Comment: @Jackowski, mostra outros erros também, mas a origem do erro é essa da ai por isso coloquei só esse aí. Depois da explicação no comentário do Diego Felipe eu entendi o que você quis dizer e ao aplicar no meu arquivo AndroidManifest funcionou só não entendo porque tem que colocar todo o endereço da activity se ela esta apenas em pacote filho, mas tudo bem. O importante é que resolveu vou editar sua resposta pra ficar mais explicativa e colocar como resolvido.